# Exporting the data from DB by passing the data from input csv file and saving the results in csv file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, loops, foreach, sql-scripts

```
$SQLServer = "Server Name"
$SQLDBName = "DB Name"
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Sampath\SQL\DynamicSql\CustomerData.csv"
#SQL Query for periodic payments.
forEach ($data in $csvData){
$SqlQuery = "SELECT ID,CUSTOMERNUMBER,ENTITYNUMBER,ACCOUNT FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[XXXX] WITH(NOLOCK)    where PSTATUS = 'F' AND [entityNumber] = '$($data.ENTITYNUMBER)'"
$SqlConnection = New-Object   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=True")
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlQuery, $SqlConnection)
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($SqlCmd)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)}
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv "D:\Sampath\SQL\DynamicSql\Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

`

I Have a requirement to extract the data from SQL database based on the input data in CSV file, this input csv file having 30+ rows, so i want to fetch the data each row wise and save the all results in one out put csv file

I am trying to run the above script and it is running without error but results are not showing, Could you please suggest where i am making mistake

Comment: You should move the last line inside the foreach loop perhaps? and change the filename so it doesn't get overwritten

Comment: For debugging purposes it's helpful to have operations in discrete steps like you have but PowerShell works best when everything is pipelined. You should aim to restructure the code to `Import-Csv | ForEach-Object {...} | Export-Csv` where the contents of the `ForEach-Object` is executing your query for each row input from the `CustomerData.csv` file and outputs the `$dataSet.Tables[0]` as its result.